# Set the ItemTemplateSelector of a treeview inside a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, datatemplate

I have a problem with the user control I created. This control consists of a search textbox and a treeview. The treeview shows different data templates for different node types. So I created the usercontrol with a dependency property of type datatemplate which can be bound when using my control. Inside the control, the treeview binds to the dependency property. But sadly the treeviewtemplate selector doesn't get called.

```
<UserControl x:Class="yyy.yyy.yyy.UI.UserControls.SearchableTreeView.SearchableTreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:yyy.yyy.yyy.UI.Behaviours;assembly=yyy"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="parent"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=parent}">
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItems}" ItemTemplateSelector="{Binding TreeViewTemplateSelector}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="behaviours:TreeViewItemBehaviour.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
</DockPanel>
```

The code behind with the dependency property looks like that:

```
    public partial class SearchableTreeView : UserControl
  {
public SearchableTreeView()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeViewTemplateSelectorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "TreeViewTemplateSelector", typeof (DataTemplateSelector), typeof (SearchableTreeView), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplateSelector)));

public DataTemplateSelector TreeViewTemplateSelector
{
  get { return (DataTemplateSelector) GetValue(TreeViewTemplateSelectorProperty); }
  set { SetValue(TreeViewTemplateSelectorProperty, value); }
}


}
```

And the usercontrol is used in a xaml like that:

```
    <searchableTreeView:SearchableTreeView TreeViewTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewFieldTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Where the TreeViewFieldTemplateSelector is a class of type datatemplateselector, which allready worked before i startet to create a usercontrol out of the searchable treeview.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Or is it not possible to bind a datatemplateselector directly to a treeview?

Thanks

Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating your system by using a `DataTemplateSelector`. While it *is* true that these objects were created for this purpose, there is a much easier way to achieve your requirements. Basically, if you declare a `DataTemplate` for each data type *without specifying the `x:Key` values*, then they will be applied implicitly to all objects of the correct type:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:YourDataType">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:YourOtherDataType">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:SomeOtherDataType">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, if you put items of these data types into a collection and data bind that to a collection control, then you'll see your various items rendered as expected, but without the complications of the `DataTemplateSelector`.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, then try this instead... first remove the `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=parent}"` setting and then add a `RelativeSource Binding` for the `TreeViewTemplateSelector` property:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SearchText, 
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItems}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{Binding TreeViewTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={
        RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:SearchableTreeView}}}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            ...
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I know, that would be easier, but the problem is that I have to choose the DataTemplate not regarding to different types of the objects. There is a property inside the object which is used by the DataTemplateSelector to tell wpf which template it should use.

Comment: Thx! That was it. I found this solution some minutes ago there http://www.jayway.com/2011/05/17/bind-from-xaml-to-property-defined-in-code-behind/

The problem was that I had to bind the treeview to the dependency property which is inside my code behind file, but the data context was the view model for the control.